# Send http post request to server after internet re-connect

Tags: android, http-post, internet-connection

Is there any method to send a http post when internet re-connect back?
Below is the scenario.

**Scenario:**
1. Send a http post, for example a json data when there is no internet connection
2. the post request will automatically send to the server once the internet is connected.

Comment: Consider to use [Android Priority Job Queue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue).
This allows to enqueue the job with parameter that require network.

Comment: @MrOnyszko thx for reply. I'm trying on it, and it is working. But is there anyway to do something like onPostExecute method in AsycnTask? Mean that after the execution success I can send a ToastMessage on it.

Comment: Great! [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) will help you to send message from the enqueued job.

Comment: @MrOnyszko thx man dude....It is works

Answer (score 1):

**1. create custom broadcast receiver:**

```
private BroadcastReceiver connectionListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if ((networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) & (networkInfo.isConnected())){
                sendBroadcastMessage(getString(R.string.FORCED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED));
                Log.w(LOG, "wifi connection established");
            }
            else{
                sendBroadcastMessage(getString(R.string.FORCED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_LOST));
                Log.e(LOG, "no wifi connection");
            }
        }
    };
```

**2. register broadcast receiver:**

```
registerReceiver(connectionListener, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
```

**3. depends from what you need add permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```